# thunderbird cant connect to e-mail-provider

Tags: thunderbird

i am on u ubuntu 15.10 wily werwolf 64 bit.
when i try to connect in thunderbird to my existing e-mailaccount
thunderbird hangs while trying to connect to e-mail-provider.
(i can acess my account with the web-site from my email-provider)
Any help is welcome
Greetings
Franz

Comment: Does your email provider permit you to use external clients to connect?  Not all providers let you use thunderbird or similar to access mail.

Comment: i use thunderbird on an windows system(from which i now give the comment). Here all works well. And had thunderbird on the same Ubuntu-system up (did a new install because of graphic driver-problems).with ..this old system.. thunderbird worked.

Answer (score 0):

Ok , here's what you need to do...

1. enable IMAP
2. below steps are only for gmail ...
3. go to mail.google.com
4. sign in with your id
5. click on settings on the top right corner and then select Forwarding and Pop/Imap tab
6. Enable IMAP
7. then again open ThunderBird
8. enter your credentials
9. wait for a few minutes
10. give acess to thunderbird and you are done....